# firestore - react native - passing transaction as a parameter to a function

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to pass the transaction from within a

`db.runTransaction((transaction)=>{...`

block to a function which is exported in an external .ts file (say functions.ts). The aim is to make this external function a part of the transactional computation that is initiated in one of my other .js files let's say MyScreen.js.

So, before the transaction, the exported function would look like this:

```
static async updateDoc(ref) {
        return await ref.update("field", firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1));
}
```

After passing the transaction it will be like this:

```
static async updateDoc(ref,transaction) {
       return await transaction.update(ref,"field", firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1));
}
```

I would import this functions.ts in MyScreen.js file, then call the function like so:

```
Functions.updateDoc(my_ref,transaction);
```

I have already made this change and code seems to work. But how can I be sure that this external function is now actually a part of the original transaction? Is the fact that it is working enough to be sure that it actually is now a part of this transaction? Is there a way to check this?

Comment: What do you mean by `part of the transaction`? it won't rollback automagically unless you manually do it so in catch block

Comment: I mean, if an error happens in the external functions that I pass the transaction to as a parameter, will them, and the functions in the original document MyScreen.js that are executing in the context of this same transaction all rollback vice versa? Will they now be all in the context of the same transaction.

Comment: You misinterpret the transaction parameter here. It's only the database transaction api, it's not related to any other context somehow. If you need to rollback the database transaction you should call rollback method manually, and if you do so it doesn't rollback any other changes the code made but the database ones.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse but I think you are misinterpretting my question here. Of course I am talking about database changes... Anyways.. Thanks for the responses..

Comment: As I said you should do try{ await,, await, await} catch( transaction.rollback) and move the transaction parameter to outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

So long your external function calls are within the **same `db.runTransaction` block** with the `transaction` parameter being passed across (and still within the same `db.runTransaction` block), they're **part of the transaction** -- unless you're not using `transaction.get()`, `transaction.update()` etc. within the block.

To test it, purposely make an erroneous code or throw an error somewhere and let the `.catch()` of `db.runTransaction` block triggered, see if the transaction has been automatically roll-back.

Hope this answers your question.